# openGL: Why isn't text appearing on screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype, freetype2

I'm moving my OpenGL project over from GLUT to GLFW. Currently I am trying to get text to appear on screen using the library FreeType. I am following the tutorials from their site, but I am stuck. I believe I have it all written out, but for some reason it isn't working. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "ft2build.h"
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

FT_Library library;
FT_Face face;

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

//should only be used for key press or key release
static void key_press(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void render_text(const std::string &str, FT_Face face, float x, float y, float sx, float sy) {
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    const FT_GlyphSlot glyph = face->glyph;

    for (auto c : str) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER) != 0)
            continue;

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8,
            glyph->bitmap.width, glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glyph->bitmap.buffer);

        const float vx = x + glyph->bitmap_left * sx;
        const float vy = y + glyph->bitmap_top * sy;
        const float w = glyph->bitmap.width * sx;
        const float h = glyph->bitmap.rows * sy;

        struct {
            float x, y, s, t;
        } data[6] = {
            { vx, vy, 0, 0 },
            { vx, vy - h, 0, 1 },
            { vx + w, vy, 1, 0 },
            { vx + w, vy, 1, 0 },
            { vx, vy - h, 0, 1 },
            { vx + w, vy - h, 1, 1 }
        };

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float), data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        x += (glyph->advance.x >> 6) * sx;
        y += (glyph->advance.y >> 6) * sy;
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
}

void Resize(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    int width, height;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(-5.f, 5.f, -5.f, 5.f, 5.f, -5.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Setup()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    //used for font
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

void Display(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    render_text("TEST", face, 0, 0, 100, 100);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void Update(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    Display(window);
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
        std::cout << "glewInit failed, aborting." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FT_Error error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
    if (error) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return 1;
    }

    error = FT_New_Face(library, "Stoke-Regular.ttf", 0, &face);
    if (error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format) 
    { 
        std::cout << "font is unsupported" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (error) 
    { 
        std::cout << "font could not be read or opened" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    error = FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    if (error)
    {
        std::cout << "Problem adjusting pixel size" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //keyboard controls
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_press);

    Resize(window);
    Setup();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        Update(window);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Possibly because you have not called `glEnableVertexAttribArray (0)`? If you have a core profile, in addition to that, it may also be because you have not bound a Vertex Array Object. You also need to generate and bind a VBO. The tutorials you are following should show all of these things.

Comment: This doesn't look like core profile to me. Particularly since there are no shaders. So the use of generic vertex attributes is most likely one problem. The setup of the attributes looks odd anyway, since the vertex data seems to contain positions and texture coordinates, but only one attribute is specified.  `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` will also have to be set.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not core. But the other things I mentioned are valid... I should stop posting at 11 PM and think about sleep instead :P

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I tried adding that to the render_text function, but there was no change. What do you mean by a core profile? Relooking at the tutorial there are VBO's in it, but I am having trouble understanding how they go in the project. The tutorial is very broken up incoherent. This is what I am looking at if it helps: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01

Comment: @RetoKoradi I don't udnersand how shaders work in OpenGL. I can't seem to find a good tutorial explaining how to use them or make them. I can understand the code lookign odd. I am trying to piece together a tutorial that doesn't show complete code that I really don't understand. The only success I have currently is that it isn't crashing..

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?  Where do you generate and bind the texture object that your `glTexImage2D()` call is uploading to?